# WordPress Address and Site Address differ

Tags: urls

I have a site where the WordPress Address and Site Address to differ and they need to stay different in order for the front end of the site to be visible. This set up was created a few years ago and has worked fine since however with recent updates now seems to be causing issues.

Does anyone know if it's possible for the two URLs to differ and, if so, how? This isn't just a situation where WP core files are hosted in a subdirectory for example, the 2 URLs are different addresses!

Comment: Have you read [the support article on this topic](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)? When you say "...the 2 URLs are different addresses", do you mean different domains (eg, example.com and some-other-site.com)? If so, do the 2 domains resolve to the same server? The same IP address?

Comment: Hi, yes but that only seems to cover changing the url, the urls we have set have always been the same and it's only in recent update that we are now seeing issues. With the domains one is a sub domain of the main domains but they resolve to different servers obviously with different IPs.